# Paste data from csv to google Sheets. UIPath

Tags: uipath-studio

I have a process as shown below:
[image: Reading CSV UI Path]

Now I want to paste the csv to a googlesheet with a given link. Does anyone know what's the right way to do it? I used open browser then click to the desired tab and then paste, but this seems like a hacky way to me. Is there any better way for the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "import" function in google sheets and select your .csv-file, but it would still require some clicking.

[image]

Comment: yes! I have implemented the click method already, what I need is using `GSuite` API.